# Keyerror 1 problem while iterating an array that stores features selected by SelectKBest algori

Tags: python, pandas

I got this error

```
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

KeyError: 1
```

while looping throw an array

```
kbest_feature_corre

i = 0
while i < len(kbest_feature_corre):
    print(kbest_feature_corre[i])
    i += 1
```

array looks like this

```
             Specs       Score
16    Predictor 17         inf
40    Predictor 41         inf
41    Predictor 42         inf
102  Predictor 103         inf
103  Predictor 104         inf
105  Predictor 106         inf
107  Predictor 108         inf
120  Predictor 121         inf
121  Predictor 122         inf
122  Predictor 123         inf
123  Predictor 124         inf
124  Predictor 125         inf
125  Predictor 126         inf
126  Predictor 127         inf
127  Predictor 128         inf
128  Predictor 129         inf
129  Predictor 130         inf
130  Predictor 131         inf
131  Predictor 132         inf
144  Predictor 145         inf
145  Predictor 146         inf
146  Predictor 147         inf
147  Predictor 148         inf
148  Predictor 149         inf
149  Predictor 150         inf
150  Predictor 151         inf
151  Predictor 152         inf
152  Predictor 153         inf
153  Predictor 154         inf
154  Predictor 155         inf
410  Predictor 411  113.389284
371  Predictor 372  107.523782
316  Predictor 317  105.745269
..             ...         ...
```

I want to print all results of the array, I couldnt find what went wrong here :/
the array stores the results of applying SelectKBest algorithm for feature selection.

Comment: It is not an array, its a dataframe

Comment: `for index, row in kbest_feature_corre.iterrows():`
`print(row)`

Comment: oh, I see the issue now, I have to convert to array right?

Comment: Thanks its solved :D

Comment: @Ibrahim An array might be a good idea. You really should avoid accessing DataFrames like that.